# Why are there multiple applicationUrl in launchsettings.json in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core

```json
"https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7071;http://localhost:5130",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
```

Is the second one a fallback url or something? I couldn't find any documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the second one a fallback url or something

No, they are different urls for different protocols - one for HTTP and another one for HTTPS. Usual pattern is to accept requests both for HTTP and HTTPS and [Enforce HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu) via `UseHttpsRedirection` call.